# Loading context after application context

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I have a doubt which is similar to the one here:

[Class Loading Application Context Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376980/class-loading-application-context-spring)

But I also want to load the dependencies of the classes loaded after the application context.

Is that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I also want to load the dependencies of the classes loaded after the application context.

if they are required to be initialized with class initialization, they will get loaded

Comment: So I will have a jar file that will need to be loaded after application context is loaded. This jar will have dependencies on other jars and those too, should get loaded. Will this work?

Comment: if you try to load a class Foo from jarF and it needs class Bar from jarB at initialization time it will attempt to load it